# Custom Settings - SOQL Limit

Tags: soql, customsetting

I am new to custom settings.

My assumption is Custom Settings are part of application cache as such querying against custom settings do not count against SOQL limit.

This is my code snippet (executed from developer console).

Combinations__c is a custom setting.

```
String q='Creative';
String t='Dealer';
String a='Expand';
String sa='Included';

List<Combinations__c> sb = [SELECT ID FROM Combinations__c WHERE Queue__c=:q AND Type__c=:t AND Area__c=:a AND Sub_Area__c=:sa];
System.debug(sb.size());
```

This is my log as shown below.As you can see it is firing one SOQL query.

I am confused :(

[image]

I believed querying against Custom Settings do not count against limit.

Can someone explain why a SOQL is fired and is counted against the limit of 100 even when I am querying against custom settings ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Querying custom settings with SOQL will surely count against limits.

The way custom settings should be used is via Apex methods for custom settings, not by using SOQL on them. Using SOQL defeats the purpose of using them.

To access data from list-type custom settings use the following:

```
List<Combinations__c> mcs = Combinations__c.getAll().values(); // Prefer this
```

This avoids SOQL on them. And then you can filter them as per your need using `if` statements.

To retrieve a custom setting by `Name` you can use `getInstance` or `getValues` methods:

```
Combinations__c myCS1 = Combinations__c.getValues('your custom setting name here');
```

Comment: Thanks.

List<Combinations__c> mcs = Combinations__c.getall().values();//Prefer this and this avoids SOQL on them 

Using this I can intialize a list of the combinations (each list element comprising of one combination I assume).

After this list (mcs) is intialized can we query against this list for a particular combination of queue,type,area and subarea ?

Comment: No .Never query.Why would you query use if and get the data required .Querying will cause governor limit

Comment: @MohithShrivastava Querying allows you to filter and order the data because SOQL is good at that and will consume 1 of the 100 allowed queries only. So "never" is too strong a term.

Comment: @KeithC Yes agreed on that.It depends on context .Like if logic is lot and somebody wants to save query i would go with If ,else i would go with query itself .